# What does int() do in C++?

Tags: c++

The following code can pass compiling and will print 0 on the console. I saw similar code in STL. Does type int in C++ have a constructor? Is int() a call of some defined function?

```
int main()
{
    int a = int();
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See also: I had asked a similar question (months before seeing this question) that now has some other great answers here too: [What is a call to `char()`, `uint8_t()`, `int64_t()`, integer `T()`, etc, as a function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72367123/4561887)

Answer (score 34):

In this context,

```
int a = int(); // 1)
```

it value-initializes `a`, so that it holds value `0`. This syntax does not require the presence of a constructor for built-in types such as `int`.

Note that this form is necessary because the following is parsed as a function declaration, rather than an initialization:

```
int a(); // 2) function a() returns an int
```

In C++11 you can achieve value initialization with a more intuitive syntax:

```
int a{}; // 3)
```

**Edit** in this particular case, there is little benefit from using 1) or 3) over

```
int a = 0;
```

but consider

```
template <typename T>
void reset(T& in) { in = T(); }
```

then

```
int i = 42;
reset(i);   // i = int()
```

Comment: As a side-note, in C++11, the preferred way to di this is the syntax `int a{}`.

Comment: @Fabien I was in the process of adding that :)

Comment: I sincerely hope that `int a = 0;` hasn't fallen out of fashion yet.

Comment: @HansPassant: Let us be reminded that the reason to add this way of initializing built-in types was for generic code to work :)

Comment: Actually, it copy-initializes `a` from a value-initialized temporary `int`.

Answer (score -1):

first, we start with this syntax:

```
type    variableName = type();
```

this syntax is called **value initialization** of a *variableName*, or in other word we say a *variableName* is zero initialized.

But, what is the meaning of the **value initialization**.

if the type of a *variableName* is a built-in/scalar type like (int, char, ...),
**value initialization** mean that a variableName is initialized with the value zero.

and if the type is a complex type like (classes, structs, ...) mean that a *variableName* is initialized by calling its default constructor.

Answer (score -2):

`int()` is the constructor of class `int`. It will initialise your variable `a` to the default value of an integer, i.e. `0`.

Even if you don't call the constructor explicitly, the default constructor, i.e. `int()` , is implicitly called to initialise the variable.

Otherwise there will be a garbage value in the variable.

Comment: `int` is not a class, and has no constructor.

Comment: The question shows an example that `int()` returns the value 0. A constructor never returns any value.