# What is a call to `char()`, `uint8_t()`, `int64_t()`, integer `T()`, etc, as a function in C++?

Tags: c++, char, initialization

I've never seen this call to `char()` as a function before. Where is this described and what does it mean? This usage is part of the example on this cppreference.com community wiki page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize:

```cpp
short_string.resize( desired_length + 3 );
std::cout << "6. After:  \"";
for (char c : short_string) {
    std::cout << (c == char() ? '@' : c);  // <=== HERE ===
}
```

This wording in the description also doesn't make any sense to me and I don't understand what it's saying:

> Initializes appended characters to `CharT()`.

Highlighted in context:

[image]

### Adjacently related

1. What motivated me to study the `std::string::resize()` method was trying to learn how to pre-allocate a `std::string` for use in C function calls as a `char*` buffer. This is possible by first pre-allocating the `std::string` by calling the `my_string.resize()` function on it. Then, you can safely write into `&my_string[0]` as a standard `char*` up to index `my_string.size() - 1`. See also:

   1. [Directly write into char* buffer of std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39200665/4561887)
   2. [Is there a way to get std:string's buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7836863/4561887)
   3. [How to convert a `std::string` to `const char*` or `char*`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/347949/4561887)

      1. See [my detailed answer to this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72485404/4561887).

### Update:

1. 3.5 months after asking the original question, I [was made aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72367123/what-is-a-call-to-char-uint8-t-int64-t-integer-t-etc-as-a-f?noredirect=1#comment129992220_72367123) of this question also: [What does `int()` do in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17131911/4561887)

Comment: Is `char` considered a class? If not, this question is certainly _not_ a duplicate. Voting to re-open.

Comment: I have added more accurate dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860780/what-does-value-initializing-something-mean

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Comment: @JasonLiam, I suggest you take your own advice, and prove you can find even _one_ related SO posts for this. Neither of the 2 duplicates show initialization of integer types via `int()`, `char()`, `uint64_t()`, etc., which is the whole crux of this question. And, they are both closed.

Comment: Here is another  dupe: [What does int() do in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131911/what-does-int-do-in-c)

Comment: *"prove you can find even one related SO posts for this..."*  Here is the proof: [What does int() do in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131911/what-does-int-do-in-c)

Comment: @JasonLiam, that's a legitimate duplicate, and unlike the other "duplicates", is still an open question, which I think should be a *requirement* for being marked as a duplicate, so new answers can be added. Thank you. How did you find it though? Despite your suggestion to "just search", I did plenty of that, and it's hard to search for this topic, and Google searches like `char() in c++` weren't very productive.

Comment: I typed the following on google search bar: [what does int() mean c++](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+int%28%29+mean+c%2B%2B&client=firefox-b-d&biw=1366&bih=627&sxsrf=ALiCzsaNtXlUisOHX6JcHhjFgzCFQAsC3w%3A1662398773337&ei=NTEWY4idFLamz7sPkKmOyAU&ved=0ahUKEwjIi_CClv75AhU203MBHZCUA1kQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=what+does+int%28%29+mean+c%2B%2B&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyBAgjECcyBggAEB4QDTIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjIICAAQHhAIEA0yBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGA0oECEEYAUoECEYYAFC6AVi_BmDjCGgBcAB4AIABgQKIAaMDkgEFMC4xLjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz). You're welcome :)

Comment: @JasonLiam, I think you got lucky by starting with `int()`. None of `what does char() mean c++`, `what does uint8_t() mean c++`, `what does int64_t() mean c++`, `what does double() mean c++`, `what does T() mean c++`, etc, produce similar useful results.

Comment: @JasonLiam, I also think you were _way too fast_ in closing this without even having a true duplicate before you did so. And, I ask you to please slow down in clicking the "close" button in the future. It's insanely infuriating, especially when you didn't have an actual duplicate until your 3rd attempt. I was about to add a very thorough answer to this question myself, which is why I edited the question just now in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the constructor<sup>†</sup> for `char`; with no arguments it constructs `'\0'`. Rarely used since primitives offer other ways to initialize them, but you initialize them with `()` just like you would a user-defined class, which ensures they get initialized to *something*; `char foo;` has undefined value, while `char foo = char();` or `char foo{};` is definitely `'\0'`.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>As HolyBlackCat notes, it's not technically a constructor, because it's not a class, but it behaves like one for most purposes.</sub>

Comment: This is super weird to me. Can class-like "constructors" be called on _any_ type? Ex: `int()` is a `0` of type `int`? `uint64_t()` is a `0` of type `uint64_t`?

Comment: It's not a class, so it doesn't have constructors. Pardon my nitpicking.

Comment: `char foo();` is most-vexing-parse.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: Yep, `int()` is `0`, `uint64_t()` is `UINT64_C(0)`, etc.

Comment: @RichardCritten Apparantely `char foo();` is not considered most-vexing parse. See [Is most vexing parse a formally defined concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71937565/is-most-vexing-parse-a-formally-defined-concept)

Comment: @AnoopRana  clang/gcc beg to differ - live - https://godbolt.org/z/PdhEMKqr3

Comment: @RichardCritten It's a vexing parse alright, but not the _**most** vexing parse_. :-)

Comment: @GabrielStaples `T()` creates an object of type `T` for any object type `T` and _value-initializes_ it (i.e. calls its default constructor or zero-initializes it). A constructor _may_ be involved for class types, but won't be for non-class types or POD-like class types.

Comment: @RichardCritten I too think that it is most-vexing parse, i even commented there that it should be called MVP. But by seeing the answers posted [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71937565/is-most-vexing-parse-a-formally-defined-concept), and them pointing out that the author Scott himself **does not** consider this MVP, i don't think there is any technically correct definition that is right here.

Comment: @user17732522, you should make that another answer. It adds value beyond what the existing answers already say.

Answer (score 6):

It returns `0` with the specified type, same as `char(0)`. It's called [*value initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

The syntax mimics that of calling a default constructor for a class.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else wondering, I found the cppreference community wiki documentation for _value initialization_ here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

Comment: See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization. "Zero initialization" is not really a concept in C++, but it has a reference page because some other types of initialization, such as "value initialization", may initialize values to zero.  Here is a quote from the link above: _"Note that this is not the syntax for zero-initialization, which does not have a dedicated syntax in the language. These are examples of other types of initializations, which might perform zero-initialization."_