# Regarding struct initialization list in C++

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

I am new to C++ and have some query related to below code snippet

1. How to initialize the members of `struct trackcmdtime` using "struct initialization list - AlertTrackingState() ?

   ```
   typedef struct trackcmdtime {
      uint64_t arrive_time_ms;
      uint64_t diff_ms;
   } TrackCmdTime;


   Class Port {

    Public:
    .........

    Private:

     struct AlertTrackingState {
       Mutex mutex;                            

       RejectAlertTrackingList list;  
       uint32_t list_count;

       uint64_t req_time_ms;

       TrackCmdTime track;    // **Quest-1**

       // Initializer
       AlertTrackingState() : mutex(), list(), list_count(0), req_time_ms(0) {}  

     } _alert_tracking_state;
   }

    // Constructor
    Port::Port() :
      _alert_tracking_state()
    {
      ........   
    }
   ```

Comment: *"What is the difference in behavior if I add `track()` and `track(0)`..."* The difference is that `track()` is value initialization. This is explained in any beginner [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and various SO posts. For example, [What does int() do in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131911/what-does-int-do-in-c)

Comment: Also, one question per post.