# Initializing a pointer to a structure with an empty parenthesis

Tags: c++

I have this line of code:

```
socket_LWIP = std::make_shared <framework::tcpip::socket::SocketLwip>();
```

where `SocketLwip` is a structure that has this constructor:

```
SocketLwip();
```

we defined under the `: public` section.

---

I understand that the discussed line of code creates a pointer to this structure, but it is initialized with a `()` which I don't quite understand. What does `()` do?

Comment: Its called *value initialization* and is explained in any beginner [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: See [dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860780/what-does-value-initializing-something-mean), [dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765961/default-value-and-zero-initialization-mess) and [dupe3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131911/what-does-int-do-in-c).

Comment: I reopened this because it's not value initialization.

Comment: it's something much more obvious. `()` calls a function. `std::make_shared<framework::tcpip::socket::SocketLwip>` is the name of a function, and `()` calls it.

Comment: And as it so happens, the implementation of `std::make_shared<framework::tcpip::socket::SocketLwip>` forwards its parameters (which are `()` in this case) to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::make_shared<T>()` is a template function.  The `()` is just its parameter list, like with any other function.

The code in question is simply *calling* `std::make_shared<T>()`, where `T` is being set to `framework::tcpip::socket::SocketLwip`.

`std::make_shared<T>()` creates a new instance of `T`, forwarding its own input parameters to `T`'s constructor (which in this case, there aren't any), and returns that new instance wrapped inside of a `std::shared_ptr<T>` object.

That `std::shared_ptr<T>` object is then being assigned to the `socket_LWIP` variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering without any judgement. As it turns out this is not as trivial as it seems at first.